# Is this a form of Black Hat SEO

Tags: javascript, seo, trojan

lately i have been receiving lots of spam mail containing links such as this one
**do not click** --http: // mgatemizlik.com/galeri/de.php---

I used PHP file_get_contents() and wrote the contents to file.

This is what i got as the out put.
(EDIT this is from an active spam link)

```
    <html class="featured-panel-style-2" lang="en-US" style="background-image:url(&#39;/bin_static/back.jpg&#39;);">
    <!--
<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <!-- OptimizePress SEO options -->
    <title>$12.365,98 in 26 Days</title>
    <!-- OptimizePress SEO options end -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfourteen-ie-css' href='/media/zbinary/ie.css?ver=20131205' type='text/css'
          media='all'/>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" id="optimizepress-page-style-css" href="/media/zbinary/style.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="optimizepress-default-css" href="/media/zbinary/default.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/wap-snapfuck/static/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cookie/js.cookie2.js"></script>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css" id="op_header_css">
        p, .single-post-content li, #content_area li, .op-popup-button .default-button{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}a, blockquote{font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif}h1,.main-content h1,.single-post-content h1,.full-width.featured-panel h1,.latest-post .the-title{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}h2,.main-content h2,.single-post-content h2,.op-page-header h2,.featured-panel h2,.featured-posts .post-content h2,.featured-posts .post-content h2 a,.latest-post h2 a{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}h3,.main-content h3,.single-post-content h3{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}h4,.main-content h4,.single-post-content h4,.older-post h4 a{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}h5,.main-content h5,.single-post-content h5{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}h6,.main-content h6,.single-post-content h6{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}.site-title,.site-title a{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}.site-description{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}.banner .site-description{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:17px;font-family:"Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;color:#444}
    </style>

</head>
<body class="page page-id-394 page-template-default op-live-editor-page op-plugin masthead-fixed full-width singular">
<div class="floating-featured-panel floating-featured-panel-fluid main-content" style="width:600px;background-color:#000000;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #4f4f4f));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #4f4f4f 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #4f4f4f 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #4f4f4f 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 0%, #4f4f4f 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%, #4f4f4f 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#000000, endColorstr=#4f4f4f, GradientType=0);">
    <div id="content_area" class="">
        <div class="row one-col cf ui-sortable" id="le_body_row_1" data-style="">
            <div class="fixed-width">
                <div class="one column cols" id="le_body_row_1_col_1">
                    <div class="element-container cf" data-style="" id="le_body_row_1_col_1_el_1">
                        <div class="element">
                            <div class="op-text-block" style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;width:100%;line-height:40px;margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;">
                                <p style="font-size:42px;color:#ffffff;letter-spacing:-2px;line-height:40px;text-align: center;">
                                    <strong>How I Made
                                        <span style="color: #ff0000;">$12.365,98 in 26 Days</span> Without Spending a Dime
                                    </strong>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="element-container cf" data-style="" id="le_body_row_1_col_1_el_2">
                        <div class="element">
                            <div class="op-text-block" style="margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;width:100%;line-height:40px;margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;">
                                <p style="font-size:28px;color:#ffffff;letter-spacing:-2px;line-height:40px;text-align: center;">
                                                                                        <span style="color: #ffffff;">
                                                                                            <strong></strong>
                                                                                        </span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="element-container cf" data-style="" id="le_body_row_1_col_1_el_3">
                        <div class="element">
                            <div class="op-text-block" style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;padding-top:7px;padding-bottom:2px;">
                                <p style="color:#ffffff;text-align: center;">This Is A FREE Service. No Credit Card Required.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="element-container cf" data-style="" id="le_body_row_1_col_1_el_4">
                        <div class="element">
                            <div class="op-popup cf" data-width="700" data-open-effect="fade" data-close-effect="fade" data-open-speed="normal" data-close-speed="normal" data-border-color="#ffffff" data-border-size="15" data-padding-top="20" data-padding-bottom="20" data-padding-left="30" data-padding-right="30" data-exit-intent="N" data-trigger-time="0" data-trigger-dontshow="0" data-dont-show-on-tablet="N" data-dont-show-on-mobile="N" data-popup-id="op_popup_id_1417400621648">
                                <div class="op-popup-button ">
                                    <div style="text-align:center">
                                        <style type="text/css">#btn_1_23036882122fc5d2cf3a1bb81c3fcae9 .text {font-size:34px;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;text-shadow:#ff1a00 0px 1px 0px;}#btn_1_23036882122fc5d2cf3a1bb81c3fcae9 .subtext {text-shadow:#ff1a00 0px 1px 0px;}#btn_1_23036882122fc5d2cf3a1bb81c3fcae9 {padding:28px 38px;border-color:#000000;border-width:3px;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;background:#ff1700;background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ff1700), color-stop(100%, #ffef35));background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff1700 0%, #ffef35 100%);background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff1700 0%, #ffef35 100%);background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff1700 0%, #ffef35 100%);background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ff1700 0%, #ffef35 100%);background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff1700 0%, #ffef35 100%);filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff1700, endColorstr=#ffef35, GradientType=0);box-shadow:0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,41,0,0.5);}#btn_1_23036882122fc5d2cf3a1bb81c3fcae9 .gradient {-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;}#btn_1_23036882122fc5d2cf3a1bb81c3fcae9 .shine {-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;}#btn_1_23036882122fc5d2cf3a1bb81c3fcae9 .active {-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;}#btn_1_23036882122fc5d2cf3a1bb81c3fcae9 .hover {-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;}</style>
                                        <a href="/web/" id="btn_1_23036882122fc5d2cf3a1bb81c3fcae9" class="css-button style-1">
                                            <span class="text">Show Me How!</span>
                                            <span class="shine"></span>
                                            <span class="hover"></span>
                                            <span class="active"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="element-container cf" data-style="" id="le_body_row_1_col_1_el_5">
                        <div class="element">
                            <div class="image-caption" style="width:300px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="unsubscribe"><a href="/unsubscribe.aspx">Unsubscribe</a></div>

<script src="../../media/bbo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ignore below code (the spam link was dead).

```
 <head>
    <title>Google Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>

    <div class="formatting">

        <div class="header">
                <a class="logo-a" href="http://google.dodo.com.au/" title="Search"><img class="logo-img" alt="Search Logo" src="googlelogo.png" /></a>
        </div>

        <div id="content">Loading</div>

    </div>

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function parseQueryFromUrl () {
        var queryParamName = "q";
        var search = window.location.search.substr(1);
        var parts = search.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
          var keyvaluepair = parts[i].split('=');
          if (decodeURIComponent(keyvaluepair[0]) == queryParamName) {
        return decodeURIComponent(keyvaluepair[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
          }
        }
        return '';
      }
      google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('partner-pub-5369089308679380:2zjpxri3f14');
        customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.LARGE_RESULTSET);
        customSearchControl.draw('content');
        var queryFromUrl = parseQueryFromUrl();
        if (queryFromUrl) {
          customSearchControl.execute(queryFromUrl);
        }
      }, true);
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.google.com/cse/style/look/default.css" type="text/css" /> 

    <div class="clear"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

my questions are:

1) could this be a form of black hat SEO?

2) will this harm the machine of anyone who opens the link in there browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created a php file and used file_get_contents, did you get this on your local machine? If so let me guess, you are with dodo internet provider?

This is not pulling data directly from that link that was sent to you. The website link was already taken down before you got to it and in turn was throwing a connection error. Looks like your ISP has literally shown you their own custom google search page.

Could be wrong but what you got is unrelated.

Comment: since am still receiving this links, hopefully i can get content from one that is not blocked

Comment: it looks like the typical spam link from a hijacked (injected) website. Find your self a good spam filter. If you are using a hosted personal domain name I would recommend Spam Experts. I use them for all my domains and they filter out just about everything.